# OpenGLSL error while compiling fragment shader using UBOs

Tags: opengl, compiler-errors, fragment-shader

I am trying to get UBOs working, however I get a compilation error in the fragment shader:

```
ERROR 0:5:"(": synrax error.
```

Fragment Shader:

```
layout(std140) uniform Colors
{
    vec3  SCol;
    vec3  WCol;
    float DCool;
    float DWarm;
}colors;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?  What's the value of `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION`?

Comment: If I add #version, it gives me another error: GLSL error: #version must occur before any other statement in the program

Comment: However it doesn't complaint in the vertex shader.

Comment: Please post your *entire* shader, and tell us what line 5 is. And if you're not [using a #version declaration](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Version), please *start*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begining of your fragment shader source file (the very first line) put this:

```
#version 140
```

This means that you are telling the GLSL compiler that you use the version 1.40 of the shading language (you can, of course, use a higher version - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLSL#Versions) for details).

Alternatively, if your OpenGL driver (and/or hardware) doesn't support GLSL 1.40 fully (which is part of OpenGL 3.1), but only GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0), you can try the following:

```
#version 130
#extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : require
```

However, this one will work only if your OpenGL 3.0 driver supports the GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object extension.

Hope this helps.